# How to reset environment variable set with setx in Windows

Tags: windows, batch-file, environment-variables, command-line-tool

Initial state: `ABC_HOME C:\abc\bin\`

In the batch file the variable is changed:

```
setx ABC_HOME "%ABC_HOME%;E:\newAbc\abc\bin\"
```

How can I return to the state `ABC_HOME C:\abc\bin\`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `ABC_HOME` is defined before the start of the batch file, we can simply set a temporary variable to store the old value:

```dos
SET OLD_ABC_HOME=%ABC_HOME%
setx ABC_HOME "%ABC_HOME%;E:\newAbc\abc\bin\"
<your code here>
setx ABC_HOME %OLD_ABC_HOME%
```

If, however, you're using `setx` multiple times in the same batch file, you would have to query the registry to get the updated value, so you could use something like:

```dos
setx ABC_HOME C:\abc\bin\
FOR /F "tokens=2* delims= " %%a IN ('reg query HKCU\Environment /v ABC_HOME') DO SET OLD_ABC_HOME=%%b
setx ABC_HOME "%ABC_HOME%;E:\newAbc\abc\bin\"
<your code here>
setx ABC_HOME %OLD_ABC_HOME%
```

The reason for this is that `setx` doesn't apply to the environment of the `cmd.exe` instance that it's run in.

### Explanation

- `reg query HKCU\Environment /v ABC_HOME` uses the Windows Registry to get the value of the `ABC_HOME` variable, since this is not available in your batch environment.
- `FOR /F "tokens=2* delims= " %%a IN ('...') DO` will loop through the output of the `reg query` command and split it into three pieces.

  - `delims=`  will set the space character   as the delimiter for splitting the output
  - `tokens=2*` specifies which parts of the split output we want. The second piece will go into the `%%a` variable and the third portion and all portions after will go into the `%%b` variable. This way your variables can contain spaces.
  - `SET OLD_ABC_HOME=%%b` will set a temporary environment variable containing the contents of `ABC_HOME`.
- `setx ABC_HOME %OLD_ABC_HOME%` will set `ABC_HOME` back to the old value it had before you ran your other code. It must be at the end of your code.

### Further reading

- [Reg - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/reg.html)
- [Setx - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/setx.html)
- [Set - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html)
- [For (command) - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html)
- [Internal commands (like `SET`) - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-internal.html)

Comment: Could you please explain your script? I have never properly done batch scripting before. I don't understand the second line.

Comment: What I understand is that, you wrote the second line to get the first setx from the environment variables, because the first line doesn't store them for you.

Comment: Which means, I can just write `SET OLD_ABC_HOME %ABC_HOME%`, right? Since that is already picked up when I start the command line.

Comment: You would need to use `SET OLD_ABC_HOME=%ABC_HOME%` (note the `=`), but yes. If the environment variable is set before you start your batch file, then that is all you need to get the value. The second script it there for your reference in case you might need it for something else.

Comment: I've added an explanation of the second script and some further reading. Note that `SET` and `SETX` are completely unrelated commands. `SETX` is an executable (in `C:\Windows\System32`), but `SET` is only a part of `cmd.exe`.

Comment: I think, this is helpful. I don't have a system to try it out, but will confirm on Monday.

Answer (score -4):

To unset the environment variable, use the following syntax:

```
set "ABC_HOME="
```

Comment: This only affects the local instance of the command line. It doesn't change the registry.